# How to draw groups of bar plots, grouped by year?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to graph data that looks like this:

```
## Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
## Groups: year [?]
## 
##    year            helpnot count
##   <int>             <fctr> <int>
## 1  1975       Govt Do More   371
## 2  1975    Agree With Both   433
## 3  1975 Govt Does Too Much   245
## 4  2012       Govt Do More   199
## 5  2012    Agree With Both   530
## 6  2012 Govt Does Too Much   242
```

And I want the x axis to be helpnot, and I want the why to be the actual number of count. I want the X axis split into two groups. How do I do this? I have this which is close... but year is split on top of each bar and in groups by year. How do I fix this?

This is what I have:

```
ggplot(data = helpnotComparison, aes(x=helpnot, y=count, fill = year)) +
   geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

That produces me this:

[image]

**UPDATE**

This comes close:

```
ggplot(data = helpnotComparison, aes(x=helpnot, y=count, group=year, fill=year)) +
+   geom_bar(position='dodge', stat="identity")
```

produces me this:

[image]

But how do I get the year labels at the bottom? and why is the scale on the right showing 4 years when I only have 2?

Comment: Looks like you need to aggregate your data first. Try `aggregate(count ~ helpnot + year, data = xy, FUN = sum)`. Also, please insert your data as text, not an image. This is not reproducible and not many people will take the time to actually type out your dataset. At this point, the chance of somebody responding probably drops.

Comment: Try `aes(..., fill = as.factor(year)`. Remove `group=year`, you don't need it because fill already groups your data.

Answer (score 1):

Start with

```
data$year <- as.factor(data$year)
```

The reason you have 4 year is because it is interpreted as continuous.

Is this what you are looking for?

```
data <- data.frame(Year = c(rep("1975",3), rep("2010",3)),
                   helpnot = c("GDB","AWB", "GDT", "GDB", "AWB", "GDT"),
                               count = c(370, 430, 250, 200, 530, 250))
data

ggplot(data, aes(x  = helpnot, y = count, fill = Year)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + theme_minimal() +
  annotate("text", c(0.75,1.25,1.75,2.25,2.75,3.25), y = -15, 
           label = rep(c("1975","2010"),3), size = 2) +
guides(fill=FALSE)
```